# How to know ports are open to serve Rest requests?

Tags: quarkus

I am using Quarkus to build an application that is running on the Raspberry PI. Quarkus exposes Rest interfaces to control the PI; once Quarkus is started, Chrome is launched to serve a HTML/Javascript UI packaged within the Quarkus application.
The problem I have is that as the PI is quiet slow, I notice that when I start the browser to open the UI, the HTTP port seems not to be open yet or is not accepting any Rest requests yet and thus gets back 404. A seconds later, the port is available.

I am not sure what is the best way to detect the readiness of the Webcontainer.
I tried with this but it did not work and fires too early:

```
@WebListener
public class BrowserMain implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // Start Chrome
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: You can only get an HTTP response with response code 404 from a port that *is* open, and is serving HTTP requests.

Comment: maybe i was describing my question not in the technical correct terms. your are right that the port is obviously open if it returns 404. but my question is obviosuly about quarkus to be ready to serve the resoursoures/html/js files instead of returning 404. i am not even sure the response-code is 404. just saying it not 100% ready. i have to check when i am back at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarkus integrates with MicroProfile Health which should do exactly what you are looking for. See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/health-guide) guide for more details.

If what you are looking for is a way to programmatically know when the application is ready, then you simply have to listen for the `StartupEvent` like so:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppLifecycleBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ListenerBean");

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
        LOGGER.info("The application is starting...");
    }

    void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) {               
        LOGGER.info("The application is stopping...");
    }

}
```

To see more details check out [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/application-lifecycle-events-guide#listening-for-startup-and-shutdown-events) guide.

Comment: i want to test from within the application if it is ready and only open the browser when it know the endpoint will serve the application content; i.e. the html/js files. for sure i could from within the application call an external health endpoint. but then i could also just call the external resource/html file and see if it returns 200.
my question is if there is another way that does not involve polling. e.g. is there a way to use a servlet listener or similar to get a callback when i can be sure that the servlet container is ready and will serve my resources.

Comment: @38leinad I have updated my answer with more information

Comment: that's interesting. Startup-Event works for me. Thanks.
actually, the first thing i tried was using @Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) and it did not work. Reading the linked documentation it states "In the JVM mode, there is no real difference, except that StartupEvent is always fired after @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class)". It seems there is a difference.
...not sure if this might only be a timing issue but for me it works now consistently, whereas i was always getting a connection-refused when using @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class).